# Intellij - How to run it with nVidia

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I think here is the most suitable place for me to ask this question.

Well, `Intellij` is very lag at the beginning. I tried it run the 64 bit version of the IDE, lag reduced a lot. But it is still lagging at the beginning. I think the best solution is, run it with my `nVidia` graphics card. I added `idea64.exe`(I found the location at task manager ....\bin\idea64.exe). I launched it again. It was still lagging. I checked the `NVIDIA GPU Activity`, none.

Is that any way to launch it with nVidia? I think the `idea64.exe` is a launcher. It will run another `exe`/`jar` after we selected the project.

EDIT: What I mean by lag is, when you typed a word like `p`, the ide lagged about 1~2 seconds, after that the auto complete box popped out. If I click File, the ide also lagged about 1~2 seconds. After that it work very fine if you click it again.

Last time my graphics card software broke. `Eclipse` also have problem like this. After I reinstall the graphics card software, `Eclipse` work smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

IDE's don't use much graphics processing power. They primarily use your CPU, memory, and hard drive.

One of those is probably your bottleneck. IntelliJ is very resource intensive in all three of those categories.

Comment: I run Eclipse/Netbeans smoothly. I have a 4GB ram and 2.9Ghz 4 core intel i5  processor

Comment: 4GB is not a lot for a large project

Comment: @Jeremy It's still not your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, idea64.exe is the launcher.
Note that NVIDIA GPU Activity doesnt always show everything the gpu is running (but in this case it should).

Also its probably not an issue with graphics, an ide does not require any graphical performance. Probably some other requirement. Could you post your system specifications? and ram usage?

Just FYI to run application on gpu you can simply right click the exe and select "run with graphics processor" -> "Nvidia GPU"

Comment: Windows 7 x64. 4GB RAM. 500GB HDD. Intel i5 4 core 2.9Ghz processor. I run `Eclipse` and `Netbeans` smoothly. Another games too.

Comment: 4GB on windows 7 is not a lot, check how much free memory is left when running IntelliJ and how much memory its process is using. also do you have some large project loaded in intellij? cos that would require a lot more memory (whichever IDE you use)

Comment: It used about 400MB ram. And there is still about 1GB and half ram left... Nop it is just a small project.

Comment: You can also try to provide Intellij with more memory. Open with text editor %IntelliJ Home%/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions and edit the memory given there ("-Xms256m" is the least memory allocated "-Xmx2048m" is the maximum memory that can be allocated; units megabytes)

Comment: The startup time reduced. But it is still lagging when I typed a word. See edit. I think running it with nVidia will fix a lot of lag problem. If I run a Java game with Intel, i can only get about 10fps o_O

Comment: I seriously doubt its a graphics card issue, typing does not take any graphics requirements. Also even 10fps while typing would not be noticable, also games require a LOT more graphical power. Another option is that Intellij is running a background process that is slowing cpu ... but i doubt it. Also it could still be loading module in the background

Comment: I don't think so. Last time I left the IDE open for about half and hour after launched because I need to take a bath. After I came back it is still lagging.
(p.s. I will reply tomorrow I need to sleep now)

Comment: reinstall latest version. if that doesnt work, install previous version. it could be something in the latest build. Other than that i dont know what it could be

Comment: @Jeremy Comparing an IDE with a game is like comparing apples and oranges. They aren't the same thing, and an IDE is generally not going to go anywhere near your GPU. You need to drop the idea that you can treat games and non-games the same and just chuck GPU power at them to fix input latency.

Comment: @Jeremy my PC uses only a builtin Graphics card which is inferior to yours but I never experience lagginess even opening Android Studio,IntelliJ and Clion at the same time. Therefore the Graphic card is only a little factor. Also **why you are using x64 windows while you have 4GB of ram**?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the lists of the plugins enabled in your installation and disable those that you don't need.

It's very easy to enable all out of the box plugins in IntelliJ by mistake when you install it by repeatedly clicking on `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

To force running on Nvidia assigning in NVidia Controlpanel is not sufficient:

These steps can be used for any Swing application - e.g Java2D Demo.

1. Add these vm options (Help -> Edit Custom VM Options):

   -Dsun.java2d.d3d=true

   -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=false
2. In NVidia Controlpanel: Add the idea64.exe to be run on NVidia GPU
   Any java process using the GPU will be shown in the 'NVIDIA GPU Activity' systray.

My experience is that using the GPU for the IDE is not worth it - see below GPU/CPU usages.

However, it is extremely beneficial for Graphic Intensive Swing Application.
They make use of the GPU and you have a bit more CPU resources.

In my case, the IDE is not using much GPU except for scrolling and even here the CPU is sufficient.

With my recent Hardware the overall CPU+GPU load was higher which is bad because Laptop fans turn on quicker. So I disabled running it on GPU - see the Screenshots below.

**My Config:**

IntelliJ 2020.02 (See taskmgr) Windows 1903, Dell Laptop 15" 7540 - Xeon E-2286M - 128GB ECC RAM - NVidia RTX 5000 (16GB)

For example, if you scroll in text editor, you will see where the load is.

The following screenshots were taken while I was scrolling in the text editor.

***Running idea64.exe with GPU configs activated***
Here GPU is doing the painting work - and it is using **too much** GPU.
Main reason why i disabled the above steps.

[image: GPU]

***Running idea64.exe only CPU:***

Scrolling again - Now CPU+GPU load in total is lesser when not using the GPU.
This time the GPU load is not in  idea64.exe, but in crss.exe and dwm.exe.

It spikes up form some percentage only  - they use anyway the NVidia GPU.

[image: CPU only]

**Crashes**
I switched GPU off for Intellig2020.02 due performance reasons, but it also crashes on Laptop resume when monitor layout has changed:

1 Display -> 3xFullHD or 1Display to 2x4k and vice versa